# Parse ascii art math!

Tags: code-golf, math, ascii-art

## The task

Given a multiline string with ascii art operators and numbers, parse the expression!

## Possible symbols

Numbers: (3x4)

```
 /
/|
 |
---

___
 _|
|
---

___
 _|
  |
---

| |
|_|
  |
  |

___
|_ 
  |
---

___
|_
| |
---

___
  /
 /
|

___
|_|
| |
---

___
|_|
  |
---

___
| |
| |
---
```

Operators: (3x3)

```
 | 
-+-
 |


---


\ /
 x
/ \


 .
---
 .
```

Braces: (1x4)

```
/
|
|
\

\
|
|
/
```

## Input

A multiline string with ascii art operators and numbers. Examples in the test cases.

## Output

The string of the parsed expression.

## Test cases

Input:

```
/ ___     ___ \     ___
|  _|  |    / |  .   _|
| |   -+-  /  | ---   |
\ ---  |  |   /  .  ---
```

Output: `(2+7)/3`

Input:

```
___      /      ___
|_|     /|  \ / |_ 
  | ---  |   x    |
---     --- / \ ---
```

Output: `9-1*5`

## Rules

1. Numbers will always be single-digit
2. Since operators are one symbol shorter than numbers, they are placed one symbol lower than numbers, leaving whitespace on top.
3. All symbols have a column of whitespace between them
4. This is a code-golf challenge, so lowest byte count wins!

Comment: May we assume the lines of text are all of the same length (filled with spaces on the right when necessary to do so)?

Comment: @JonathanAllan yes

Comment: Would have been funnier to ouput the result :)

Comment: @OliverGrégoire that was the og post, but it was quickly agreed that evaluating the expression was a useless part

Comment: @Dion But printing calculated result as ASCII would make evaluation less useless I think?

Comment: I nominate this for "ugliest ASCII art challenge"!

Comment: @anatolyg it's funny cause I spent way too much time on them :D

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>46</s> 44 bytes

```apl
'/(80-)63+92145*7'[16|43|25⊥¨(×⊆⊢)2⊥' .\'⍳⎕]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVDNSgMxEL7nKeaW1pqm@9Nqn8XIEpCKUKjHCnPysMpCRQ/iXRC86xPom@RF1pnMJq0NzM6XbyfffDP@dm2u7vx6c92Hp9ebTWifZyo8Pqx6bUfnMzNeVJNlWdTzkzN9USywrrCch@7j53P0@xa6NnTv45LuGqZOh90XiVz29L5fKYKkVkNZhd23ttA0DfDh7BJC@lIgXy2nKfOIkTETwyxhYwgBOgHDAxuridFK7dsVS26XmnFRatWgMJQcN@MKzIqw5Z8onaIs1bhB3gNph@5edK0MwcFGEz6M40NSWvnTQYVfsQ0Y5scYIJaiNeFkL2KXZyX2SAVyEeaIvBUUJ6Q1xrG2MtZ/FWYOI@1EKmHPY54keiFPOq89tC/@Dw)

`⎕` evaluated input, must be a character matrix

`' .\'⍳` replace spaces with 0, `.`s with 1, `\`s with 2, and everything else with 3

`2⊥` base-2 decode the columns

`(×⊆⊢)` split on zeroes

`25⊥¨` base-25 decode each group

`16|43|` mod 43, mod 16

`'/(80-)63+92145*7'[` `]` use as indices in the given string

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>154</s> 139 bytes

```python
s=zip(*input().split('\n'))
i=0
while s[i:]:d=3**(max((s+[' '])[i+1])>' ')+i;print'+/5(_41_7802*6__-9)3'[hash(tuple(s[i:d]))*3%67%21];i=1+d
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYzbqsIwEEXf/Yq8SGYSYm3rXeqPtCEIFTpQYzCRc6H/XjNyTiDsxdrsCT9pePhqnmPzSwEU@fBKgKsYRkogOy8RF9SsF18DjTcRWzrZU9/USsH9@g0QdSuFtNiSLi1eMqOmc3iST1IXW3Cb0u0P60rtnDNHrGU7XOMA6RXGG/C13iKqernbL6vSnqkpdT/PshDOOcGPs@v@sfNTzvwnFgXHipuJC3ZGG/aZjckkcpHXH/5bFZ9JNvIN)

Answer (score 5):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>69</s> 61 bytes

Anonymous tacit prefix function. Requires `⎕IO←0`.

```apl
{('+-*/()',⎕D)['∆JV⍺TgucKmre3Ha'⍳⎕AV[94|2⊥¨,⌿⍵⊆⍨∨⌿32≠⍵]]}⎕UCS
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qG@qp/@jtgkG/6s11LV1tfQ1NNV1gIIumtHqjzravMIe9e4KSS9N9s4tSjX2SFR/1LsZKOsYFm1pUmP0qGvpoRU6j3r2P@rd@qir7VHvikcdK4BcY6NHnQuAYrGxtUDFoc7B/9OAVjzq7XvU1fyod82j3i2H1hs/apsIlAwOcgaSIR6eQDUKQBZQnYmCkTFQibq@Qnx8vAIIgOgYGKsGSAJxDYirD6L0QOI1NWARXW1dkCiQrasLZCnUxEAYUA36YNVAEXUuhG2GliDbYHaB1MBsiq@BiACpGJBdIBU1cAMVKkCSNRCLwKYC1YDtUwcA)

`⎕UCS` convert characters to code points

`{`…`}` "dfn"; argument is `⍵`

`('+-*/()',⎕D)` the involved symbols followed by the **D**igits

`[`…`]` index into that using the following indices:

`'∆JV⍺TgucKmre3Ha'⍳` indices in this string (missing elements get index=length) of

`⎕AV[`…`]` index into the **A**tomic **V**ector (the character set) using the following:

`94|` the division remainder when divided by 94 of

`2⊥¨` the base-2 evaluation of each of

`,⌿` the vertically joined and flattened

`⍵⊆⍨` segments of the argument, as indicated by trues in

`∨⌿` the vertical OR-reduction of

`32≠⍵` the Boolean mask indicating where the argument is different from 32 (space)

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 152 bytes

```javascript
f=(s,i=0,a=s.split`
`,c=a[n=0][i],x=1)=>c?"*3-425()6+9/7081"[c=='/'?6:c=='\\'?7:[x=3,4,5,6,9].map(c=>n+=Buffer(a[c/3|0])[i+c%3]*c)|n%47%16]+f(s,i-~x):''
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY7dioMwEIXvfYpSkCQ1MXZt7baQCnuxL9DLKG2IScnixq6xxQXZV3eT/RkYzjfnzMC8iYdwsje3gdiuUfOsGXTYsAwL5lJ3a81wiS5YMsEty2puajyyNWJHWS5XOdk8bSEqkj3dZc/rJZeMAQrK4hCgqkC5O/CR5XiDt7jA@zp9Fzco2dEm7OWuteqh4JLmU1YjbhIZ5/VKosnGm128LupEh1fI14gOAMyys65rVdp2V6hhrz7uplcQaAdQ2ivRvJpWnT6thIA26kHd0Bjro6E7Db2xV4gQmunifD4vQgWt/imavPiewkyDpCGYvB8skpBgeybE02KKql/6O6E/@975Bg)

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 67 bytes

```
⭆⪪⭆θ§αＩ⭆⟦θηζε⟧÷⊖℅§λκ³²A℅⁺⁴⁰÷⌕”$⌈O⁴εΦa↙M∕³↧ＦωＧ↙σ⎇C(｜？⊞¦﹪ω←2Ｉ0C⁻sⅉ”ι³
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XU7fT4MwEH7fX3HhqcQiRn3zqQxRQsTlpombM6SBxjUiTlaXxfR/x7amE9frd7/vvqvXvK8/eDsMs152isyVMa93fEPmm1aO408KTOVdI/aEU5jy7bj4bKprCt8UxAuFvFOp3MlGkFTUvXgXnRINue8b2fGW@C0thbcwDClcnIfOBiwwemou4rUSPZm1X1tyeTbel8muIcENY8jYw/WiSArGWFE4fVvgEp@yJMVyibiYZyWmiGmSPyJiiRhQkJbNkl0NA8QAVVU5aCPeP8bxi2E1ibVxKu2gHcDBVrXPGbHfvpUlO7Whnvyl9QGuN/71fBydRBBFEcAenLWz1nrYPu/bqX81fbjV8Rr@Idq1Pw) Link is to verbose version of code. Assumes 4 input strings of equal length (space padded if necessary). Explanation:

```
   θ                                First input
  ⭆                                 Map over characters and join
        ⟦θηζε⟧                      All four inputs as a list
       ⭆                            Map over strings
                  λ                 Inner string
                 §                  Indexed by
                   κ                Outer index
                ℅                   Take the ASCII code
               ⊖                    Decrement
              ÷     ³²              Integer divide by literal `32`
      Ｉ                             Cast to integer
    §α                              Index into uppercase alphabet
 ⪪                    A             Split on literal `A`
⭆                                   Map over substrings
                            ⌕...ι   Find their indices in compressed data
                           ÷     ³  Integer divide by 3
                        ⁺⁴⁰         Plus literal `40`
                       ℅            Convert to ASCII
                                    Implicitly print
```

The compressed data represents the literal string `GAARAATEYKBKAAAKKKAAAKHKRZRXFBDRNZRRYSFNRDRRDBIURRRNRR` which contains the pattens that result from the calculation, padded with `A`s to place them at the appropriate offset to generate the desired ASCII character.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 36 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ỴZ⁶=ẠƊ€œp$“¢Ọ/’,“642-*+)9(8/17035”ḥⱮ
```

A monadic Link accepting a list of characters which yields a list of characters.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///h7i1Rjxq32T7cteBY16OmNUcnF6g8aphzaNHD3T36jxpm6gA5ZiZGulrampYaFvqG5gbGpo8a5j7csfTRxnX////XV4iPj1cAARAdA2Nx1QApIK4B8fVBlB5IogYoDhLS1dYFCQPZurpAlkINVwyEBdWiD1YPFAEA)**

#### How?

```
ỴZ⁶=ẠƊ€œp$“¢Ọ/’,“642-*+)9(8/17035”ḥⱮ - Link: list of characters, I
Ỵ                                    - split at newline characters
 Z                                   - transpose
         $                           - last two links as a monad - i.e. f(X):
     Ɗ€                              -   for each, last three links as a monad:
  ⁶                                  -     the space character
   =                                 -     equals? (vectorises)
    Ạ                                -     all?
       œp                            -   split (X) at truthy indices of (that)
                                     -     (...call the result A) 
          “¢Ọ/’                      - base 250 int = 170548 (salt)
                “642-*+)9(8/17035”   - list of characters "642-*+)9(8/17035" (domain)
               ,                     - pair -> [salt, domain]
                                   Ɱ - map across A with:
                                  ḥ  -   Jelly's hash function with salt and domain
```

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>54</s> <s>40</s> 39 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
"2(-1 0/ 9 6*)+"Ž´Š«|€SøJð4×¡JÇ2δβŽ4w%è
```

<s>Can definitely be golfed some more with smarter magical integers (including changing the `ā‡` to for example `Åβ` or changing the order of the charcters in the strings), but I'm pretty bad at those kind of challenges personally, so this will do for now.</s>
-14 bytes thanks to *@ovs*, because he is skilled in these kind of magic integer challenges. ^_^

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fyUhD11DBQF/BUsFMS1Nb6ejeQ1uOLji0uuZR05rgwzu8Dm8wOTz90EKvw@1G57ac23R0r0m56uEV//8r6CsoxMfHg3ENEMLY6Bgd6CvEcOnXABnxNWBcA8YKYAySrYGJASEIgUAMyDI9ELeGCyFcA8dgtfoQFpgE6tfV1lXQ1dVVUKhQANMgvSAahkHqYGyQLhS5GrhbwfYC7QcA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##XVCxSgNBEO33K4YFIZrbrAmHYJrUSZPC9mBRsLBRwcQkMJVNPsHWdIFYiBwiSJpdrs1H5EfOmdnsiVl4N2/fzL6ZuYen65u72xrzUD7r4f3jdNIHnS38T6bH00m8Dmrda5kunFu4hIuz07autr6s3vxmsX95vwrfo/CRh1e/GoVlb1fuPqttPjsJ6zrzX4PagnMO@HAsElNIgYB8txw6nEDSWTJtwzJxY4gBqiKywxMr9aSo5M5S4@0wShQKdnegGi9OzUE8o7f4UJV0UOzDngyeJfFjHB96r7ifbEVAAQhkw6SlFSDOxnuQpv5kbCC1NjL50nv@MzL3PM6Nhz0S0p4xB/Avh82s0pf6/wI).

**Explanation:**

```python
"2(-1 0/ 9 6*)+"      # Push this string
                Ž´Š   # Push compressed integer 45783
                   «  # Append it to the string: "2(-1 0/ 9 6*)+45783"
|                     # Push all input-lines as list
 €S                   # Convert each line to a list of characters
   ø                  # Zip/transpose; swapping rows/columns
    J                 # Join each inner list (column) together to a string
     ð4×              # Push a string of 4 space characters: "    "
        ¡             # Split the list on that
         J            # Join each inner list of strings to a single string
          Ç           # Convert each string to a list of codepoint integers
            δ         # For each list of integers:
           2 β        #  Convert from a base-2 list to a base-10 integer
              Ž4w%    # Modulo-1078 on each value
è                     # And then (modulair 0-based) index them into the string
                      # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

[See this 05AB1E tips of mine (section *How to compress large integers?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `Ž´Š` is `45783` and `Ž4w` is `1078`.

Comment: [40 bytes](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fyUhD11DBQF/BUsFMS1Nb6ejeQ1uOLji0uuZR05rgwzu8Dm8wOTz90MJzW70Otxud21R7dK9JuerhFf//K@grKMTHx4NxDRDC2OgYHegrxHDp1wAZ8TVgXAPGCmAMkq2BiQEhCIFADMgyPRC3hgshXAPHYLX6EBaYBOrX1dZV0NXVVVCoUADTIL0gGoZB6mBskC4UuRq4W8H2Au0HAA) by using code points and base conversion to convert strings to integers. I haven't tried other bases than 2, so there is probably still something shorter.

Comment: @ovs Thanks! That's indeed a lot better. And in your approach I can remove the map for another -1, since most of the builtins vectorize.